# Get an alternative DateTime for checking the licence term

Tags: windows, security

There is a Software with one year licence term.
On the term's expired, some users set the system's current date to several days back and continue using it.

Is there a method in Windows 7+ to get the real DateTime  or to get the alarm that the time is changed before some illegal actions? 
Maybe something in Windows System which is changing surely everyday, every minute to compare to that datetime value and the current system time to be sure that all looks correct before illegal actions?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the date on the computer, it can be modified (an internal clock is set by the BIOS, then by the OS - and this can be modified).

You may alternatively check an external time source, typically an [NTP server](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/) (make sure you query a high stratum one), directly in your code.

This requires Internet connectivity, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I would better play with TimeSpan and will fix it at the activation time as = 0 (also synchronize remote Date with the Activation Server date).. and then will store the span value during App working time and will check them with some date type DB fields, which should be equal to actual date. )))